# Error (HttpError 400) de valores al enviar datos con Api a GoogleSheets desde Excel con Python

Tags: python, excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

Hola tengo este error al Enviar datos con un API a GoogleSheets desde Excel con Python:

> Error (HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets) json returned Invalid value at data.values (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue).

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from Google import Create_Service #Archivo librería tomada de la Web "Google.py"
import win32com.client as win32 #Libreria para trabajar con Windows y Office
import json #Libreria necesaria para no tener errores de formatos de fecha con archivos Json

# Crea la instancia para Abrir archivo de excel y seleccionar la hoja y el rango de celda

xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Control de Temperaturas de Horno.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets('Datos de Control')
rngData = ws.Range('A1').CurrentRegion() # Con esta función toma todos los datos de una tabla con formato.

# Accesa a al ID web de googlesheet, ademas usa el archivo json de las credenciales para la cuenta de servicios de API de google.

gsheet_id = '1QZ3zpLJTaBUtjgKdUqq6J2pqh2CP0v9Dd46qBWQXZvY'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '\client_secret.json'
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

rngData = json.dumps(rngData, indent = 4, sort_keys = True, default = str)

response = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=gsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range='Datos Hornos!A1',
    body=dict(
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        values=rngData
    )
).execute()

wb.Close(r"C:\Control de Temperaturas de Horno.xlsx")
```

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor edita tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias por el consejo ya lo agregué como texto...